# Sorting with std::maps in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, stl

What sorting algorithm does `std::map` uses? Will it be efficient to use `std::map` to sort a set of keys and some values associated with it rather than storing key-values in 'std::vector>` and using sort function?

In short for sorting which is better in terms of performance:

```
std::map<int,int> a;
//insert some key-values
for(std::map<int,int>::iterator it=a.begin();it!=a.end();it++)
       std::cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
```

vs

```
std::vector<pair<int,int>> a;
//insert some data into a
sort(a.begin(),a.end())
int size= a.size()
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   std::cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort just keys, then use a std::set.  It's a map without any "values".

Whether this is a good idea depends on your data set.  For small datasets this is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are implemented with some *flavors* of  Balanced Binary Search Trees ( AVL, Red-Black Tree, etc).

No it won't be efficient to simply sort a set of values using maps, unless they have some kind of *associations* , there are several others sorting algorithms to do that, depends on your data sets, distributions, etc.

Look into [*`std::sort`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) too

Answer (score 1):

> to use std::map to sort a set of values by storing those values in
>   keys and use some dummy literals for values associated with those
>   keys?

I am not suggesting you do the above, but there is already a data structure for the usecase `storing those values in keys`

It's called `std::Set`

> What sorting algorithm does std::map uses?

Since it is implemented as a balanced binary search tree, The keys would already be sorted if you do a inorder traversal.

But there is no standard way to access the "actual tree structure" of an instance of std::map.